# Get all values in my added column using PHP (codeigniter)

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I am studying the dbforge, and trying to apply it with my website. My basis or guide is the localhost/phpmyadmin where you will create a new table, i am done with the part of table name, name,type,attribute,length of the column and also the adding the column(see the picture below) [image].

Question: How can I retrieve all the post value?

Note: I tried to echo json_encode($_POST); im only getting 1 value.

**View**

```
 <form id="new-table">
   <div class="col-md-6">
    <label>Table Name:</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="type" value="new_table">
    <input type="text" class="form-control border-input" name="table_name" id="table_name"><br>
    <div class="text-danger" id="table_name_error"></div>
</div>
<!-- col-md-6 -->
<div class="col-md-3">
    <label>Columns:</label>
    <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control border-input"  name="table_name" id="table_name"> -->
    <input type="text"  class="form-control border-input" id="number_of_column" >
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
    <br>    
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-fill btn-wd" onclick="addColumn()">Add</button>
</div>
<!-- col-md-3 -->
</div>  <!-- row-->
<!-- <input type='button' value='Add Children' id='addButton' class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"> -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <h6>Name</h6>
        <input type="text" class="form-control border-input" name="field_name" id="field_name">
        <div class="text-danger" id="field_name_error"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <h6>Type</h6>
        <select class="form-control border-input" name="field_type" id="field_type">
            <option value="volvo">Varchar</option>
            <option value="saab">Int</option>
            <option value="mercedes">Date</option>
            <option value="audi">Text</option>
        </select>
    </div> 
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <h6>Length/Value</h6>
        <input type="text" class="form-control border-input" name="field_length" id="field_length">
        <div class="text-danger" id="field_length_error"></div>
    </div> 
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <h6>Default</h6>
        <input type="text" class="form-control border-input" name="field_default" id="field_default">
        <div class="text-danger" id="field_default_error"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <h6>Attributes</h6>
        <input type="text" class="form-control border-input" name="field_attributes" id="field_attributes">
        <div class="text-danger" id="field_attributes_error"></div>
    </div> 
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <h6>Null</h6>
        <input type="text" class="form-control border-input" name="field_null" value="null"><br>
        <div class="text-danger" id="field_null_error"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="append">
        <div id="TextBoxDiv1">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>  <!-- row -->

<div class="text-right">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-fill btn-wd">Update Profile</button>
</div>
</div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>
</form>
```

**Controller**

**JS**

**My creating new column function**

```
function addColumn() 
{
  var i = 0;
  var columns = document.getElementById("number_of_column").value;
  for(i=1;i<=columns;i++)
  {
  var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' );

  newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<div class="col-md-2">'+
  '<label>Name</label>'+
  '<input type="text" class="form-control border-input" name="field_name[]" id="field_name[]">'+
  '<div class="text-danger" id="children_fname_error"></div>'+
  '</div>'+
  '<div class="col-md-2">'+
  '<h6>Type</h6>'+
  '<select class="form-control border-input" name="field_type[]" id="field_type[]">'+
  '<option value="volvo">Varchar</option>'+
  '<option value="saab">Int</option>'+
  '<option value="mercedes">Date</option>'+
  '<option value="audi">Text</option>'+
  '</select>'+
  '</div>'+
  '<div class="col-md-2">'+
  '<h6>Length/Value</h6>'+
  '<input type="text" class="form-control border-input" name="field_length[]" id="field_length[]">'+
  '<div class="text-danger" id="field_length_error"></div>'+
  '</div>'+
  '<div class="col-md-2">'+
  '<h6>Default</h6>'+
  '<input type="text" class="form-control border-input" name="field_default" id="field_default">'+
  '<div class="text-danger" id="field_default_error"></div>'+
  '</div>'+
  '<div class="col-md-2">'+
  '<h6>Attributes</h6>'+
  '<input type="text" class="form-control border-input" name="field_attributes" id="field_attributes">'+
  '<div class="text-danger" id="field_attributes_error"></div>'+
  '</div>'+
  '<div class="col-md-2">'+
  '<h6>Null</h6>'+
  '<input type="text" class="form-control border-input" name="field_null" id="field_null"><br>'+
  '<div class="text-danger" id="field_null_error"></div>'+
  '</div>'


  ); 


  newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#append");
}
document.getElementById("number_of_column").value = "";
}


    ** My submit form**



 $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#new-table").on('submit',function(e){
        $.ajax({
          url: base_url+"formsubmit/new_form_submit",
          type: "POST",
          data: $(this).serialize(),
          success:function(data)
          {
            var result = JSON.parse(data);

            if(result === "success")
            {
              $("h5").html("");
              success_message("#success-message-edit-content-1","Update Successfully!");
              window.setTimeout(function(){location.href=base_url+"administrator/view_content"},2000);
            }
            else{
              $("#table_name_error").html(result.table_name_error);
              $("#field_name_error").html(result.field_name_error);
              $("#field_type_error").html(result.field_type_error);
              $("#field_length_error").html(result.field_length_error);
            }
          },
          error: function(data) {
            alert('error');
          }
        })
        e.preventDefault();
      })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, I see you already have an input with name="field_name" and in the addColumn() 
function you are also adding another input with the same name.

When you have a input named "field_name" in the form and later you again dynamically add another input with the same name again, they replaces one another and there is only one of their value present in the post data with that same name.

You can use array inputs here, like

```
<input name="field_name[]" ... />
<input name="field_type[]" ... />
...
<input name="field_name[]" ... />
<input name="field_type[]" ... />
...
<input name="field_name[]" ... />
<input name="field_type[]" ... />
...
```

You will get the Post array like:

```
Array
(
    [field_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => fv1
            [1] => fv2
            ....
        )
    [field_type] => Array
        (
            [0] => ftv1
            [1] => ftv12
            ...
        )
)
```

So for parsing:

```
$fields_array = array();
$no_of_fields = isset($_POST['field_name'])? count($_POST['field_name']) : 0;
for ($i=1; $i<=$no_of_fields; $i++) {
  $tmp = array();
  if (isset($_POST['field_name'][$i])) $tmp[] = $_POST['field_name'][$i];
  if (isset($_POST['field_type'][$i])) $tmp[] = $_POST['field_type'][$i];
  ...
  if (!empty($tmp)) $fields_array[] = array();
}
```

It is a little bit errorprone(assuming field_name, field_type will have arrays of same number of elements, if one is missing the parallel serial among them will be corrupted) approach.

Better to use counter for the fields.
For example:

```
<input name="no_of_fields" value="1"/>
```

Which's value will be increased in each addition.

And your form be like:

```
<input name="field_name_1" .../>
<input name="field_type_1" .../>
...
<input name="field_name_2" .../>
<input name="field_type_2" .../>
...
<input name="field_name_3" .../>
<input name="field_type_3" .../>
...
```

For parsing on the server side, you can go for:

```
$fields_array = array();
$no_of_fields = isset($_POST['no_of_fields'])? intval($no_of_fields) : 0;
if ($no_of_fields > 0) {
  for ($i=1; $i<=$no_of_fields; $i++) {
    $tmp = array();
    if (isset($_POST['field_name_'.$i])) $tmp[] = $_POST['field_name_'.$i];
    if (isset($_POST['field_type_'.$i])) $tmp[] = $_POST['field_type_'.$i];
    ...
    if (!empty($tmp)) $fields_array[] = array();
  }
}
// Now process/output the $fields_array;
```

Comment: If i make it array in my view,now how can I retrieve the other values?

Comment: I got an error "Undefined index: field_name[]". Things that i've done: 1) Removed my input fields in my view(name etc).,So it is now on my js but when I tried to json_encode Im having an error.

Comment: About "1) Removed my input fields in my view(name etc).,So it is now on my js" - did you mean you are creating dynamic form data in js and submitting it via ajax? In that case please check the submitting data first.

Comment: "I tried to json_encode Im having an error" - Did you mean you are getting js error when trying to JSON.stringify(...data..) or in serverside php json_decode? In both case I will suggest to check the generated data(Firebug's console will help) first.